# Book recommedation for real analysis

Tags: real-analysis, book-recommendation

I am currently self-studying 'Understanding Analysis' by Abbott and couldn't even make it through Chapter 1 as the exercises became unintelligible after the first few sections, probably because this is my first proof-based subject. Could you recommend me an introductory book on single-variable analysis that has doable problems?

Comment: Abbott is at the lower end of difficulty. So if you are having issues with it I would suggest enrolling in a university course where a professor can guide you. If you are hell-bent on self-study, you should first look into a preparatory proof book like "How to Prove It" by Velleman and for real analysis I would recommend "Analysis I" by Terence Tao over Abbott. It is not much easier than Abbott but it has far, far more details and hints in Exercises.

Comment: Thanks, I'll check it out.

Comment: I had the same problem and I figured that I forget the theorems after like 2 days , the reason of that I dont spend much time with concepts (i finish a section in like 1 hour) this was my problem may be it is not as yours but I think if you just like me try to read each old section before the next and try to memorise the theorems

Comment: That's an interesting point.